# Perl Binary/PCAP regex

Tags: regex, perl, binary

I have a pcap file for which I need to match on the string of `^@^@GET /test/test.jpg"`  If I try to do a perl string regex it doesn't see the non-printable characters of ^@^@ and will not match.  If I try using the hex version of `\x5E` to match the `^` that is a no go as well.  How can I conduct a regex match on a binary/pcap file to match against non-printable characters such as `^@^@` ?  Thank you

All thank you for the suggested postings.  However, after trying the suggested postings I don't get the data I am trying to captured.  Apologies ahead of time for not posting more details if I may have confused you.  I am trying to capture the data in the text below starting with

^@^@GET /mac/_base_v1/modules/header-search/images/magnify.jpg to ^@^@GET /mac/_base_v1/images/icons/facebook.png HTTP/1.1^M

However, using the suggested captures return all the data in the text and not the substrings within the larger text.  Hope this clarifies my obejctive and again thank you for the posting and sorry for any inconvenience.

```
§~ìd<82>TÉ^V±N^KohÆ<9b>Ïò<9e>X¬L^GÏNr6þLÑ4^Gì^U<8d><91>~¡Ö^WçmJG~<9e>ÁCb<98>L^G^W³Doý¦·&aV<86>^Wt^[Gò^^Âwú"ÂÌ¹^LÔ5<94>j¦5ýw÷!^K<86>"^V3^FÞBlO=<8b>NLu><8f>/<86>Þö^@è«<8c>^X»<88>ð^?âß~IVl^[Ö^Ym<9d>utà÷Öíá×Î`%A'fMr+ôc^D%^R=Ûö^Nö<81>§^HØÜ<9a>nV2åÎ^Q"BÍÕ<8a>Îo©v^Tö·ý<96>äÏ¿^F½Ïâ^D^]ÏS½ã¥yÇ«tií^[<8d>^N"m    ®<98>^B¹^Uk½^SÑÛ0i5^Xn<8d>T5<95>jÅüGâP^Bÿë{~-Wyu^S<93>5Á!å<8b>þÑ^[±å<91><9b>ØÅWq^OÐYVBT^KâdðèÅ<8b>ãGH<83>RÂì­<8d>Á^_^TÊ<88>R    ò^Rb<82>ÿÃ6<85>Ý^U^W^_®áHì®3_´ µõX3^C?VÉÌï}ÌÏ0Ô<83>Z+<91>ÔúËÃ«à0ÁeS9ñØk^Y<88>QÒÚ97<83>¢l<88>^Cñ/         ^.BM^BD^F^G<ÐI<9c>^\^þ^M¼^]$²?£ªüó?Ý^Mã^[ôûðä¿^G^@Èð¶ú8ª^A^@$<9f>ÚOé'^A^@6^@^@^@6^@^@^@^@!^^L# àøG.±N^H^@E^@^@(C@@^@@^FëvÀ¨^@\@^D^K^Q5¾^@P<91>~@^ZÉÇsÐP^P~¿ß¼^@^@$<9f>ÚO:(^A^@¾^A^@^@¾^A^@^@^@!^^L# àøG.±N^H^@E^@^A°¯k@^@@^F}ÃÀ¨^@\@^D^K^Q5¾^@P<91>~@^ZÉÇsÐP^X<81>`UÊ^@^@GET /mac/_base_v1/modules/header-search/images/magnify.jpg HTTP/1.1^M
Host: www.microsoft.com^M
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0^M
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5^M
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate^M
Referer: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client^M
DNT: 1^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
^M
$<9f>ÚOW^R^C^@Q^D^@^@Q^D^@^@àøG.±N^@!^^L# ^H^@E^@^DC^?Ä@^@7^F³×@^D^K^QÀ¨^@\^@P5¾ÉÇsÐ<91>~A¢P^X^P^PJþ^@^@HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
Cache-Control: max-age=900^M
Content-Type: image/jpeg^M
Last-Modified: Thu, 20 May 2010 22:26:01 GMT^M
Accept-Ranges: bytes^M
ETag: "80e2276d6bf8ca1:0"^M
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5^M
VTag: 438546932400000000^M
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"^M
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET^M
Date: Fri, 15 Jun 2012 02:34:11 GMT^M
Content-Length: 632^M
^M
ÿØÿà^@^PJFIF^@^A^B^@^@d^@d^@^@ÿì^@^QDucky^@^A^@^D^@^@^@K^@^@ÿî^@^NAdobe^@dÀ^@^@^@^AÿÛ^@<84>^@^C^B^B^B^B^B^C^B^B^C^E^C^C^C^E^E^D^C^C^D^E^F^E^E^E^E^E^F^H^F^G^G^G^G^F^H^H


        ^H^L^L^L^L^L^L^N^N^N^N^N^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^A^C^D^D^F^F^F^L^H^H^L^R^N^L^N^R^T^P^P^P^P^T^Q^P^P^P^P^P^Q^Q^P^P^P^P^P^P^Q^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^PÿÀ^@^Q^H^@^V^@^Y^C^A^Q^@^B^Q^A^C^Q^AÿÄ^@i^@^@^B^C^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^G^E^F^H     ^A^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^A^C^C^B^C^D^K^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^B^C^D^Q^E^F^@!^R^S^GA"b^T1<92>Ò<93>T<94>Ô^U^VV^W^Q^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ÿÚ^@^L^C^A^@^B^Q^C^Q^@?^@èrÿ^@<9a>Ø0¤åY^U¶^C^PâDnDÉ
<88>Ò<8d>8^G`A*Q&<80>^MÉÐ@Ús^<9e>Ì»[íwî<9f>ËÆSx_&Ï:ñk<80>ÜyN<90>T<96>ë^]×ÖÓ<8a> %(}-¨ö^M^EæF-<82>)<87>^Rí<8a>Þ´)$-
<86>Á^D^QB^H(Üh1/ñ¾<93>þ¯^GÜ<8d>^C<8f>'¹KÉúpÍ<86>^Kíµ1´Û&Ã/îÉ<91>n}<89>­!Á½P¥²^R¯       :
§Rº³<99>JÇbÝoX<84>¨¶ì~uºõuäK<83>2Kßm<96>Ü<94>¢^[lºTSÆ<84><97>^Vàl<86>Â»¦º^FE<8f>«¶<8c>³^^<8d><91>Xe<89>P'µÍ<8c>ð¨¨Ü^PA¡^D^PA^GpE4
^_9 <90><8b>"çå#ðÅr<9c>¦èB<9b>Üp^O^V<80><9e>béð®zÍûZ^A"TäÛ<99>T(j\PÊL4GS^\²ÈOp7E<84>R<9e><8d>é Vþ_<9e>~<89>7çí<9f>S ÿÙ$<9f>ÚOj^R^C^@6^@^@^@6^@^@^@^@!^^L# àøG.±N^H^@E^@^@(²U@^@@^F|aÀ¨^@\@^D^K^Q5¾^@P<91>~A¢ÉÇwëP^P^?RÙ<86>^@^@$<9f>ÚO±^R^C^@¯^A^@^@¯^A^@^@^@!^^L# àøG.±N^H^@E^@^A¡<8b>^K@^@@^F¢2À¨^@\@^D^K^Q5¾^@P<91>~A¢ÉÇwëP^X<81>`hè^@^@GET /mac/_base_v1/images/icons/facebook.png HTTP/1.1^M
Host: www.microsoft.com^M
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0^M
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5^M
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate^M
Referer: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client^M
DNT: 1^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
^M
$<9f>ÚO_$^E^@<91>^C^@^@<91>^C^@^@àøG.±N^@!^^L# ^H^@E^@^C<83>^@F@^@7^F4^V@^D^K^QÀ¨^@\^@P5¾ÉÇwë<91>~C^[P^X^OðCæ^@^@HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
Cache-Control: max-age=900^M
Content-Type: image/png^M
Last-Modified: Mon, 24 May 2010 18:00:50 GMT^M
Accept-Ranges: bytes^M
ETag: "be4f6fb6bfbca1:0"^M
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5^M
VTag: 791763032400000000^M
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"^M
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET^M
Date: Fri, 15 Jun 2012 02:34:11 GMT^M
Content-Length: 442^M
^M
<89>PNG^M
^Z
^@^@^@^MIHDR^@^@^@^M^@^@^@^M^H^F^@^@^@rëä|^@^@^@^YtEXtSoftware^@Adobe ImageReadyqÉe<^@^@^A\IDATxÚ<8c>R=KÃP^T=ï%ý^P'ÁEEìÔÁÅE¨^Hnnö^WtvvPp^S
.*(ØMéâ,^U^G]tvQ(:)8^HRÑbm<92>&i<9a>^O^S_^´xué]NÞ=÷Üó^N/¬PÚÞ]_.®bÀÚ©<9e>í±êéMÄRÃ<83>j^Pù6Ô<96>n<83>§^Y!<86>²
<8a><85>)äÆGäÙõ>Q©ÝÊïÐ³ ~h&X<86>n+-æû<82>¸2i^E-ÝJ<9c>\S8I^QuÊO<8e>J¼{|Eå¸N¸P<8a>Ú^FXöïõR^Rï<9f>Þ^Q/%<99>^\1?WÚ<8a>x6¹ÊþÚ^Rf§'þ<85>?<¹ÆÑùw¦^^[ªftÀ]E6ê^O/ð|^_ó39y~n^Zh¼ih4uÄsRätÀÆ^VVúN?Õ¸(K,^_\¢Z»¢<99>b'Û2À^CN^HÏó$^Z<96><83><98>'"<91>I<8d>ü^^BÞ%<84>i&á»¶%Þ<85>r¡<98>^W"Ñä*!t]<97>h<9b>^]ù^G<90>
^\¨aàl2®lüîk<9a><96><88>lSl¦¢HÌ^?       0^@^C=¢X>ä      Ó^@^@^@^@IEND®B`<82>$<9f>ÚO<96>$^E^@6^@^@^@6^@^@^@^@!^^L# àøG.±N^H^@E^@^@(Ü^G@^@@^FR¯À¨^@\@^D^K^Q5¾^@P<91>~C^[ÉÇ{FP^P^?²ÔR^@^@%<9f>ÚO;>^H^@¬^A^@^@¬^A^@^@^@!^^L# àøG.±N^H^@E^@^A<9e>òR@^@@^F:îÀ¨^@\@^D^K^Q5¾^@P<91>~C^[ÉÇ{FP^X<81>`^B¤^@^@
```

Comment: Could you use Net::Pcap to parse the data for you and give you the payload? A hexdump tool will also help you see what's actually in there.

Comment: Hi brian d foy, I suppose Net::Pcap could do the trick.  Not too familiar on how to leverage it at this point.  I am trying to automate this process as much as possible.  Once I have the match for the data of interest I will use a hex editor to look at the data.  However, I would like perl to produce the data of interest to pass to the hex editor. Any suggestions on Net::Pcap would be appreciated.  I will start researching :)

Answer (score 3):

You can match the binary string `^@^@GET /test/test.jpg` with the pattern `/^\x{00}{2}GET /test/test.jpg$/`;

Answer (score 1):

`@^@` is not a non printable character for Perl. The `@` denotes an array, which probably goes wrong at this point. The caret `^` matches the beginning of a string. Will fail as well.

Have you considered escaping the `\@` if you want a printable character `@` or looking up the byte value of the non-printable character (0x00) and matching that (`/\x00/`)?

So you either want the regex

```
m{\x{00}\x{00}GET /test/test.jpg}
```

or

```
m{\^\@\^\@GET /test/test.jpg}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = 'This is a @^@GET /test/test.jpg test';
if ($s =~ m{(\@\^\@GET /test/test.jpg)}) {
    print $1;
}
```